# ASMX Security No Authentication

Tags: service, web, asmx

How do you prevent a third party from using an ASMX web service if you don't force users to authenticate?

Comment: Answer: Authentication.  You cannot find out who a user is unless the user somehow proves it.  To put it differently, you cannot create trust from thin air.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it will come down to who they are and how they access your web service. And the degree of risk they propose.

You could use simple "Security through Obscurity" where you don't tell people about the service. This is usually a very very poor solution. In fact it can be positively dangerous as you don't get to know who knows - so it's a real risk.

You could authenticate the machines and processes and not the people. Say for example IP addresses.

But at the end of the say you need to some form of authentication to determine any kind of filtering.